# Dart : N-ary tree implementation

Tags: flutter, dart, tree, n-ary-tree

I have a university project where I need to implement an N-ary tree in dart.

This is my node so far

```
class Node {

    Node parent; // parent of the current node
    List<Node> children; // children of the current node
    int id;
    String actualMessage;

    Node (int id, String actualMessage){
        this.id=id;
        this.actualMessage=actualMessage; 
        children  = new List<Node>();
    }
}
```

I am stuck on how I should implement the following methods. I will try to explain what I need with the following example

A is root and has 3 children : B, C and D. B has 2 children: E and F. E has 1 child: G.

[Check Tree example here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MI5BF.png)

1. How to add a root / parent node /child node to the tree => How to add A , B and E
2. How to remove a node from the tree. => How to remove B. It should remove its children too.
3. How to retrieve the "actualMessage" of the parent and all possible children when parent is passed as parameter (on a single level) => How to get the actual message on A ? Method should return actual message on B, C and D too
4. How to retrieve the number of nodes from the longest path => number of nodes from the longest path is the path from root to the last node. It is 4 in my case.
5. How to retrieve the number of nodes and list of all parents of the tree on any node getting to the root. =>  number of nodes from G is 4 and list of all parents from G is E, B and A.

Any code or info on how to do the above will be much appreciated. It's my third day where I am stuck on the same thing.

Thank you

Comment: This question is not suitable for this forum, please follow the guidelines from here - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow, that's a lot you're asking for :P

I've tried out the first 2 requirements and here is the code that can help you fulfil them.

```
Node root = new Node(0, "A"); // Your root node
```

I'll be showing the results of a Pre-Order traversal on the tree.

1. Adding a New Node:

```
void addNode(Node parent, Node newNode){
  newNode.parent = parent;
  parent.children.add(newNode);
}
```

After running:

```
Node b = new Node(1, "B");
addNode(root, b);

Node e = new Node(2, "E");
addNode(b, e);
```

Pre-order traversal result:

```
Visited Node A
Visiting child:
Visited Node B
Visiting child:
Visited Node E
```

This agrees with your structure :D

2. Removing a Node (and its children), I used the 'actualMessage' as the comparison. You can use whatever you think is better as per your implementation:

```
void deleteNode(Node treeRoot, String message){
  Node n = treeRoot;
  if(message == n.actualMessage){
    print("Deleted Node " +n.actualMessage);
    n.parent.children.remove(n);
    return;
  }
  for(int i = 0; i < n.children.length; i++){
      deleteNode(n.children[i], message);
  }
}
```

After Running:

```
deleteNode(root, "B");
```

Pre-order traversal result:

```
Deleted Node B
Visited Node A
```

Again, Seems to be working fine :D

> Ill update this as soon as I get more time

Comment: Thank you @Sidak for your answer.  I know that's a lot and I am sorry for that. That was very helpful! Hope you'll have time to update your answer. Meanwhile, I marked this answer as accepted this answer since it helps for the first parts.